# Simple unit conversion in python using tkinter returning PY_VAR3 instead of intended value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple unit converter using tkinter and I'm running into an issue where I get back PY_VAR3 instead of the value I'm calculating.

I've tried using .get() and .set() but I'm unsure of how they work. Below I've attached my current code.

```
from tkinter import *
def convert(value, type1, type2):
    global convertedValue
    if(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Meters"):
        convertedValue = value * 1000 #tried convertedValue.set(value * 1000)
    elif(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Centimeters"):
        convertedValue = value * 1000 * 100
    elif(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Miles"):
        convertedValue = value * .621
    elif(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Yards"):
        convertedValue = (value * .621) * 1760
    elif(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Feet"):
        convertedValue = (value * .621) * 5280
    elif(type1 == "Kilometers" and type2 == "Inches"):
        convertedValue = (value * .621) * 5280 * 12
    convertedValue.set(convertedValue)
window = Tk()
value = StringVar()
metric1 = StringVar()
metric2 = StringVar()
convertedValue = StringVar()
greeting = Label(text ="Unit Converter", font = ('Times', 30))
greeting.pack()
frame = Frame(master= window, width = 250, height= 250)
frame.pack()
expressionFrame1 = Entry(frame, textvariable=value, font= ('Arial', 25))
expressionFrame1.grid(row=0,columnspan=4)
expressionFrame2 = Entry(frame, textvariable=convertedValue, font= ('Arial', 25))
expressionFrame2.grid(row=1,columnspan=4)
metricChosen1 = Label(frame, textvariable=metric1, font= ('Arial', 25))
metricChosen1.grid(row=0,column = 4,columnspan=1)
metricChosen2 = Label(frame, textvariable=metric2, font= ('Arial', 25))
metricChosen2.grid(row=1,column = 4,columnspan=1)

options = [
    "Kilometers",
    "Meters",
    "Centimeters",
    "Miles",
    "Yards",
    "Feet",
    "Inches",
]
dropdown1 = OptionMenu(frame, metric1, *options)
dropdown1.grid(row = 0, column=5)
dropdown2 = OptionMenu(frame, metric2, *options)
dropdown2.grid(row = 1, column= 5)
buttonConv = Button(master=frame,
    text="Convert",
    width=15,
    height=5,
    bg="gray",
    fg="white",
    relief=RAISED,command=lambda: convert(value, metric1, metric2))
buttonConv.grid(row = 3, column= 2)

mainloop()
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM5nw.png)

Comment: What have you tried on using `.get()`?

Comment: You say you've tried calling `.get()`, but you don't show that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to get a Value from a StringVar(), IntVar(), DoubleVar() or BooleanVar(), you have to use allways the .get() method. To set a Value, you allways have to use the .set(x) method to set the Value. The value x in the .set Method is the value you want to set (can be a normal value or a Variable).

So, when you pressed the Button to Convert the Value, you have to make shure, taht you use the .get() Method like that:

```
command=lambda: convert(value.get(), metric1.get(), metric2.get())
```

To get rid of the problem in the convert function, I would sugesst you to convert the value from the Stringvar to a local float or double variable and use that to callculate your units. At the end of the function, you can set the Converted Value Variable again:

```
convertedValue.set( "local variable with the result" )
```

The Rest of the code looks acctually quite okey. ☻